# SQL that retrieves rows relative to its foreign keys in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

The problem is that I'm unsure if their exists a technical or standardized approach to what I'm trying to accomplish.

I've provided a basic approach that 'results' in the intended outcome, but I want to know if the foreign keys can be utilized inside the SQL to return the relative rows.

```
CREATE TABLE sessions(
SessionID INT(80) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Key VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
Username VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Online VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
Status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
IP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
SocketID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Latest VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Since VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SessionID),
FORIEGN KEY (Username) REFERENCES users(Username)
)

CREATE TABLE Users(
UserID INT(80) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Username VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
Password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName VARCHAR(50),
LastName VARCHAR(50),
BirthDate VARCHAR(50),
RegistrationDate TIMESTAMP(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
PRIMARY KEY (SessionID),
FORIEGN KEY (Username) REFERENCES friends(Sender, Reciever)
)

CREATE TABLE Friends(
FriendID INT(80) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Sender VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Reciever VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Sent_Timestamp VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
Response_Timestamp VARCHAR(16),
PRIMARY KEY (FriendID),
FORIEGN KEY (Sender, Reciever) REFERENCES Users(Username)
)

"SELECT * FROM Sessions, Users, Friends WHERE Sessions.Username = Users.username AND Sessions.Username = Friends.Sender OR Session.Username = Friends.Reciever";
```

Now what SQL can I execute in order to return all the relative rows of a single row in the sessions table. Notice the ForiegnKey on the Username. Is it a combination of SELECT Statements that defines the relationship inside the SQL?

EG: `SELECT * FROM Sessions, Users, Friends WHERE Sessions.Username = Users.username AND Sessions.Username = Friends.Sender OR Session.Username = Friends.Reciever";`

Or does SQL have a function that can interpretate the relationship between the foreign keys and return all the relate-able and relevant results with a more sophisticated SQL query? Or is my previous SQL statement the correct approach?

Comment: I apologize if this isn't a proper question since it's asking for advice/knowledge on a situation rather than a hard solution/solve to a problem.

Comment: I correct approach would be to use explciit JOINs, implciit "comma" joins have been out of favor for decades now. Foreign keys only enforce referential integrity; SQL has nothing to auto-retrieve all related data.

Comment: Your query has nothing to specify which rows in `Users` should be returned, so you're going to get a cross product with the entire `Users` table.

Comment: A multi-column foreign key can't reference a single column in another table. You need separate foreign keys for each of `Sender` and `Receiver`.

Comment: You can't have bidirectional foreign key relationships, it causes a chicken-and-egg problem. You can't create a Friend before creating the Users, but you can't create a User before creating Friends.

Comment: Edited the SQL and yeah i noticed the chicken and egg problem when i was writing the SQL.